# Is there a way to dynamically name prometheus labels in javascript?

Tags: javascript, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

For example I am trying to create this prometheus metric

```
const wishlistReleasesProm = new prometheus.Gauge({
          name: path,
          help: 'test'
        });
```

path is a string. But it does not let me. I tried `${path}`but it did not work either. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Past the error message, or the full code can be helpful.

Comment: @JianZhong "Error: Invalid metric name"

Comment: You need to check what metric name the prometheus.Gauge accept. This tip is very clear.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of dynamical setup for both label names and metric names. More than that, this goes against best practices for using Prometheus and can lead to numerous issues including low performance and high maintenance costss because of the big storage needed for TSDB. You can read about that here https://www.robustperception.io/cardinality-is-key/

Also you are confusing label and metric since you are asking about label name, but provided an example with a try to dynamically set up a metric name.